# How to mark line in target file in case line matched

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

my bash script read each line from file - /tmp/file.CSV until EOF

And find if this line match  line in other file - /tmp/target.CSV ( in case of full match bash script need to add "+" in the beginning of the matched line )

for example

```
  line="/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11" ( from /tmp/file.CSV )
```

we see that $line have full match with line:

```
    1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK ( from /tmp/target.CSV )
```

then we need to add "+" on the line in **/tmp/target.CSV** as

```
   +1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK
```

please advice how to do that with **sed** or **awk** or maybe **perl one liner** in my bash script

```
 more /tmp/target.CSV


 1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK
 2,Ama,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen",comrse,temporal,OK
 3,ArnTel,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe",Coers,FAIL
 4,Ahh,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EMA/EM/llk/AAe",Coers,FAIL
 142,ucell,LINUX,/VPNAAonfig/EMEA/EM3/Ucell/ede3fc34,Glo,G/rvrev443,OK

 more file.CSV

 /VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11
 /VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen
 /VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe
 /VPConfig/EME/EM0/TTR/Ar
 /VPNAAonfig/EMEA/EM3/Ucell/ede3fc34
```

**my bash code**

```
 while read -r line
 do

 grep -iq "$line" /tmp/target.CSV 

 if [[  $? -ne 0 ]]
 then
       echo  "$line" NOT MATCH target.CSV
      else

     sed .................

     fi
 done <  /tmp/file.CSV
```

Example of expected results (according to  the files /tmp/target.CSV  file.CSV )

```
     more /tmp/target.CSV


    +1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK
    +2,Ama,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen",comrse,temporal,OK
    +3,ArnTel,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe",Coers,FAIL
     4,Ahh,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EMA/EM/llk/AAe",Coers,FAIL



more file.CSV

+/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11
+/VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen
+/VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe
 /VPConfig/EME/EM0/TTR/Ar
+/VPNAAonfig/EMEA/EM3/Ucell/ede3fc34
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" 'FNR==NR{ a[$0]++; next} $2 in a { $0 = "+" $0 } 1' file.csv target.csv
```

Output:

```
+1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK
+2,Ama,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen",comrse,temporal,OK
+3,ArnTel,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe",Coers,FAIL
4,Ahh,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EMA/EM/llk/AAe",Coers,FAIL
```

Or

```
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" 'FNR==NR{ a[$0]++; next} { print ($2 in a ? "+" : " ") $0 }' file.csv target.csv 
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" 'FNR==NR{ a[$0]++; next} { $0 = ($2 in a ? "+" : " ") $0 } 1' file.csv target.csv
```

Output:

```
+1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK
+2,Ama,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen",comrse,temporal,OK
+3,ArnTel,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe",Coers,FAIL
 4,Ahh,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EMA/EM/llk/AAe",Coers,FAIL
```

And this one is valid whether each line starts with a single space or not:

```
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" 'FNR==NR{ a[$0]++; next} { sub(/^ ?/, $2 in a ? "+" : " ") } 1' file.csv target.csv
```

Try

```
awk -F\" -v OFS=\" 'FNR==NR{ a[$0]++; next} { sub(/^ ?/, $2 in a ? "+" : " ") } 1' file.csv target.csv
```

#### Update (1)

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{ sub(/[ \t\r]*$/, ""); a[$0]++; next} { t = $4; gsub(/(^"|"$)/, "", t); sub(/^[ \t]*/, t in a ? "+" : " "); } 1' file.csv target.csv
```

Output:

```
+1,ull,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11",fnt,rfdr,OK
+2,Ama,LINUX,"/VPNfig/EME/EM8/Franlecom Eana SA/Amen",comrse,temporal,OK
+3,ArnTel,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EME/EM3/ArmenTem Armenia)/ArmenTe",Coers,FAIL
 4,Ahh,LINUX,"/VPConfig/EMA/EM/llk/AAe",Coers,FAIL
+142,ucell,LINUX,/VPNAAonfig/EMEA/EM3/Ucell/ede3fc34,Glo,G/rvrev443,OK
```

#### Update (2)

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR{ sub(/[ \t\r]$/, ""); a[$0]++; b[FNR]=$0; next} { t = $4; gsub(/(^"|"$)/, "", t); r = " "; if (t in a) { c[t]++; r = "+" }; sub(/^[ \t]*/, r); } 1; END { for (i = 1; i in b; ++i) { t = b[i]; sub(/^[ \t]*/, t in c ? "+" : " ", t); print t > "/dev/stderr" } }' file.csv target.csv > new_target.csv 2> new_file.cs
```

Comment: In some cases I found that some lines should be remarked with + but they not marked

Comment: @maihabunash Perhaps make sure they're line endings are in UNIX format. Try passing `sed -i 's|\r||'` to all files. And whatever may be the problem, do update your post.

Comment: It may also be possible that you have trailing spaces in your `file.csv`. You can ignore them by changing `FNR==NR{ a[$0]++; next }` to `FNR==NR{ sub(/[ \t\r]+/, ""); a[$0]++; next }`.

Comment: I try awk -F\" -v OFS=\" 'FNR==NR{ sub(/[ \t\r]+/, ""); a[$0]++; next } $2 in a { $0 = "+" $0 } 1'  ( but this not add any "+" in the file ???

Comment: @maihabunash Can you upload your files in pastebin.com?

Comment: Sorry it should have been `FNR==NR{ sub(/[ \t\r]+$/, ""); a[$0]++; next }`. Forgot the `$`.

Comment: see my update - I add new line - this line shuld match but the awk code not add the "+"

Comment: @maihabunash I see. I'll pass with the new update. Good luck with your question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58279/discussion-between-maihabunash-and-konsolebox).

Comment: where  is the new Update?

Comment: @maihabunash What I mean is I'll pass. But I made an update again anyway. Please check.

Comment: OK I need to make tests now , I will be back soon with results..................................

Comment: seems that work until now well , but can I add something important to me , if you can - can you add "+" also on the  file.csv ( so "+" will add on both files ) , hope it not comlicated the solution

Comment: @maihabunash What would be the condition to add + on file.csv?

Comment: if line from file.csv has match on the file target.csv then this line in file.csv shuld be remark also with +

Comment: OK THX I WILL CHECK THIS WILL BACK SOON THX ALLOT

Comment: I THINK YOUR SOLUTION IS VERY GOOD _ WELL DONE FOR YOU REALLY GREAT JOB

Answer (score -1):

Try this Perl's one liner:

```
perl -pi -e '$_="+".$_ if($_=~m{/VPNfig/EME/EM3/Ucll/ucelobeconn/6EKoHH11}is);' /tmp/target.CSV
```